# Write values to td with no id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to edit values in a table where the rows/cells are generated dynamically so I they have no html id.  I am currently doing this by going to tr:nth-child, but this only works if the value I set for rowID corresponds to that position in the table. Ex: If I remove the 3rd item from the table, the item with rowID=4 is now the 3rd child of the tr, and the following code will edit the wrong cells.

```js
// I get the rowID like this:
rowID = $(this).data("row-id");


// This is what I'm doing now to edit the table:

        $('#or-table tr:nth-child(' + rowID + ') td:nth-child(3)').html($('#aff-selector').val());
        $('#or-table tr:nth-child(' + rowID + ') td:nth-child(4)').html($('#editor-code').val());
        $('#or-table tr:nth-child(' + rowID + ') td:nth-child(5)').html($('#editor-lat').val());
        $('#or-table tr:nth-child(' + rowID + ') td:nth-child(6)').html($('#editor-long').val());
```

```html
<!-- This is the table: -->

<table id="or-table" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped bootgrid-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column-id="id" data-identifier="true" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
            <th data-column-id="aff" align="center">Affiliation</th>
            <th data-column-id="code">Symbol Code</th>
            <th data-column-id="lat">Latitude</th>
            <th data-column-id="long">Longitude</th>
            <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why not give them an ID when you generate them?

Comment: Do your `tr`s have any information on it? You have the header cell in your HTML, but not an example of a data row...

Answer (score 2):

You could dynamically assign the row ids using a for loop and then redo that calculation every time you remove a row.

```
function foo () {

var rowCount = $('#or-table tbody tr').length;
for (i=1;i <= rowCount; i++) {
   $('#or-table tbody tr:nth-child("'+i+'")').data('row', i);
}

}
```

You could run this function on $(document).ready and again after the removal of any row.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [HTMLTableElement interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement). BTW, why would you need to remove a `<td>`? Wouldn't be easier just to remove the data **inside** the `<td>`?

1. Get a reference to the `<table>`

   > -`var or = document.getElementById('or-table');`
2. Then use the `.rows` property.

   > -`or.rows[0] // first row of table`
3. Next, use the `.cells` property.

   > -`or.rows[0].cells[2] // first row, 3rd cell`
4. Finally, edit the value of cell with `innerHTML` or `textContent`.

   > -`or.rows[0].cells[2].innerHTML='test' // set first row, 3rd cell content to "test"`

The following Snippet demonstrates the use of the HTMLTableElement interface:

#### SNIPPET

```js
var or = document.getElementById('or-table');

function seekCell(row, cell) {
  var data = document.getElementById('data').value;
  var row = parseInt(row, 10);
  var cell = parseInt(cell, 10);
  var rows = or.rows.length; // max number of rows
  var cells = rows * 6; //max number of cells

  (row > rows) ? row = rows: row = row - 1;
  (cell > cells) ? cell = cells: cell = cell - 1;
  var tgt = or.rows[row].cells[cell];
  tgt.innerHTML = data;
}
```

```css
[type='number'] {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is the table: -->

<table id="or-table" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped bootgrid-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-column-id="id" data-identifier="true" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
      <th data-column-id="aff" align="center">Affiliation</th>
      <th data-column-id="code">Symbol Code</th>
      <th data-column-id="lat">Latitude</th>
      <th data-column-id="long">Longitude</th>
      <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>NONE</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>KILL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>02</td>
      <td>NONE</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>EDIT</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<form id='f1' name='f1' onsubmit='seekCell(row.value, cell.value)'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Row &amp; Cell</legend>
    <label>Row:
      <input id='row' name='row' type='number' min='1' max='99'>
    </label>
    <label> <small>Note: The first row is the &lt;thead&gt;</small>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label>Cell:
      <input id='cell' name='cell' type='number' min='1' max='6'>
    </label>
    <label><small> Note: The number will be adjusted for 0-Index enumeration. (i.e. input -1)</small>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label>Data:
      <input id='data'>
    </label>
    <input type='submit'>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```